# I am trying to read a folder path but I am getting the 'str' has no attribute 'dir' error message

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = "C:\Users\Ankuran Das\Desktop\Pyhton\holiday_100"
  working_folder = args.dir
  gmm = load_gmm(working_folder) if args.loadgmm else generate_gmm(working_folder, args.number)
  fisher_features = fisher_features(working_folder, gmm)
  classifier = train(gmm, fisher_features)
  rate = success_rate(classifier, fisher_features)
  print("Success rate is", rate)
```

And I am getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fishvec.py", line 135, in 
    working_folder = args.dir
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dir'

Comment: Well, `args` is a string. Not an array, not any other object. As simple as that.

Comment: Why *would* it? What did you expect `"C:\Users\Ankuran Das\Desktop\Pyhton\holiday_100".dir` to give you?

Comment: I am expecting to get the folder holiday_100 to be loaded into working_folder
What should I do any suggestions @jonrsharpe

Comment: Why would that be the case? It's just a string. Look into os.path or pathlib for parsing and manipulating of paths.

Comment: Maybe you want to `os.chdir(working_folder)` instead

Comment: @Ivan I prefer not to change a global state with `os.chdir` if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable **args** is a simple string variable not an object with some attribute **dir**.
Just change the line:
**working_folder = args.dir**
with
**working_folder = args**
and it should point to your desired directory.

Answer (score 0):

import os

`if __name__ == '__main__':
  args = r"C:\Users\Ankuran Das\Desktop\Pyhton\holiday_100"
  print(os.getcwd())`

with the help os.getcwd() you can check your current working directory as well.